Can you overwrite the memory of a union, if no members are active?
The following program sets the table, eats, and clears the table. The place where the dish goes is cleaned before and after eating. Is that allowed according to the C++23 standard? Or is it undefined behavior? Demo.
class Dish {
    // ...
};


class Table {
public:
    Table() {
        std::memset(&dish, 0, sizeof(dish));
        ::new (&dish) Dish();
    }

    ~Table() {
        dish.~Dish();
        std::memset(&dish, 0, sizeof(dish));
    }

    void Eat() {
        dish.Eat();
    }

private:
    union { Dish dish; };
};


int main() {
    Table t;
    t.Eat();
}


Is Dish trivially copyable?

I believe it's legal under [basic.life]/6: "Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways.... Such a pointer refers to allocated storage, and using the pointer as if the pointer were of type void* is well-defined..."

Agree with Igor regarding the main question, but note that memset in the ~Table() can be optimized out if the destructor is inlined, and that's exactly what happens in the godbolt link you provided (look at main in the assembly). If you intend to zero memory for security reasons, you should use something like SecureZeroMemory (or implement yourself). Otherwise, I see no need for that memset.

A standard way would be memset_explicit, if it will be implemented. Currently all mayor compilers say, there is no such function (demo). The _s functions are not implemented either, see this answer.

Because memset writes to an object as if it were a sequence of char values, it does not violate the strict aliasing rule, [basic.lval]/11:

An object of dynamic type Tobj is type-accessible through a glvalue of type Tref if Tref is similar ([conv.qual]) to:

Tobj,
a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to Tobj, or
a char, unsigned char, or std​::​byte type.

If a program attempts to access ([defns.access]) the stored value of an object through a glvalue through which it is not type-accessible, the behavior is undefined. If a program invokes a defaulted copy/move constructor or copy/move assignment operator for a union of type U with a glvalue argument that does not denote an object of type cv U within its lifetime, the behavior is undefined.

It is not guaranteed that this operation will produce a valid value for the object. But this doesn't matter in your case, because you explicitly construct a Dish object (so its constructor has the responsibility of setting up a valid value, regardless of what was there before.) There is nothing here that would make it UB to perform the memset operation.

I'm not sure, how this applies to my case. There is no object accessed here (Dish is not alive when its memory is overwritten). I must admit, that I don't understand how accessing an object through a char is not UB. E.g., this is UB: demo.

@Dr.Gut the object is present, it simply isn't alive.

@Dr.Gut in that godbolt demo, it's not the access through char that has UB. The UB comes from using the pointer value after it has been overwritten.

Are you sure, there are two kinds of objects? One that is alive, and another, that is present? In my English understanding (not C++), if we are talking about an object, it has to be alive in order to talk about it. If something doesn't exist, how do you name it?

@Dr.Gut An object can exist before its lifetime starts and after its lifetime ends. For example [basic.life]/1.2 says that an object's lifetime doesn't start until its initialization is complete, but [class.cdtor] talks about what you can do with an object while it is under construction (at which point its lifetime has not started yet), which wouldn't make any sense if there was no object there.
